# How to unmount nfs on shutdown of system via Network Manager

Tags: mount, 15.04, network-manager, shutdown, nfs

I use network manager and mount a NFS drive via a custom script

`/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99nfs.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

IF=$1
STATUS=$2

if [ "${IF}" = "eth0" ] && [ "${STATUS}" = "up" ]; then

        mount /media/media
        exit $?

elif [ "${IF}" = "eth0" ] && [ "${STATUS}" = "down" ]; then
        umount /media/media
fi
```

But when I shutdown my computer it does not switch of. Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> revealed that the stop job for unmounting `/media/media` does not stop running.

How can I properly umount on shutdown? I think the unmount has to happen before NetworkManager disconnects.

Answer (score 2):

Based on adonis' comment I was able to fix this as follows:

- create a new file `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-down.d/99nfs.sh`
- make it executable
- contents:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  logger "down: unmounting nfs shares PREDOWN"
  umount /media/media
  ```

of course I could also have checked for the interface, but I did not this time.

**edit**
This solution broke. See [Networkmanager: dispatcher.d/pre-down.d is not executed on shutdown anymore](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681109/networkmanager-dispatcher-d-pre-down-d-is-not-executed-on-shutdown-anymore) for followup.