# Networkmanager: dispatcher.d/pre-down.d is not executed on shutdown anymore

Tags: network-manager, shutdown

I am using this (https://askubuntu.com/a/674106/39966) solution to unmount a NFS on shutdown.
But now I discovered, that in most of the cases, when I shutdown the computer via the XFCE menu, the pre-down script is not executed (I see this by a logger message which is not appearing)

Answer (score 2):

[Others](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=196157) where having the same problem.

It looks like there was a [change in Network Manager](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=701242#c10) which no longer closes the connection on shutdown of Network Manager. I was able to add a systemd service to be executed when the network goes offline.

I created a file `/etc/systemd/system/networkdown.service` with the content:

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/umount /media/media
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

This seems to work.

Comment: You are missing an install section.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/683873) worked well for me. But... I had to add an [Install] block at the bottom of the above unit file.

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecStop=/bin/umount /media/media
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```