# Automount slow shutdown and reboot

Tags: shutdown, reboot, automount

I have autofs mounting nfs and cifs shares. Everything is great except for slow shutdowns and reboots. I find the message "A stop job is running for Automounts filesystems on demand" with a 3 min countdown. So this is what is causing the delay. But I can't find where to adjust the 3 minutes to something shorter or to direct autofs to unmount everything immediately. What can I do to speed up shutdown or reboot?

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem for ages and I use autofs extensively in my local network. The only way I have found around the problem is to open a terminal and issue the command:

```
sudo systemctl stop autofs
```

After this the systems shut down as normal.

Answer (score 0):

It should be because the network interface get deactivated **before** the autofs service is stopped.

I encountered the same issue in KDE where I set up a WIFI connection from the GUI and have the "`All users may connect to this network`" option untick, making the interface get deactivated before autofs.service is stopped during the shutdown.

Adding umount command to scripts under /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/ doesn't help either as [they are not invoked in the shutdown](https://askubuntu.com/questions/681109/networkmanager-dispatcher-d-pre-down-d-is-not-executed-on-shutdown-anymore).

Found 2 workarounds

1. One option is to tick the "`All users may connect to this network`"
   option in the Network Manager. It will maintain the WiFi even KDE
   exit. Then create and the following line to
   `/etc/polkit-default-privs/local`. Otherwise the KDE will keep
   prompting for password to activate the connection every time it
   starts up or wakes up from a sleep.

   ```
   org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.system           yes
   ```
2. Another option is to create a shell script to execute `sudo umount -a -t nfs4` (need to setup NOPASSWD in sudoers first) and add it as a "logout" script either through the GUI "System Setting -> Startup and Shutdown -> Autostart -> Add Logout Scripts..." or simply put it in the `~/.config/plasma-workspace/shutdown` folder.